# Do EM waves cancel out permanently in this example?

Tags: photons, reflection, interference, polarization

If we emit two photon rays one from each source 1 and 2 and after they reflect on mirrors to reach the same trajectory they should cancel out in the case their phases are opposite 100% but will any EM radiation be present leaving spots A and B? If the answer is that the radiation leaves A and B then what if we put a polarizer at spot C? Will the fact that they cancel out at that spot C make the polarizer not doing any attenuation effect to the rays?

[image]

Comment: Remember there will also be beams going in (roughly) the directions of your black arrows labelled "semitransparent mirror 1" and "semitransparent mirror 2".

Answer (score 1):

When two light beams cross, they don't influence each other. The field in the intersection area indeed gets interference maxima and minima, but this is just a property of the field at a point — that the sum of two light waves gives a zero or an increase.

However many other beams one beam may have crossed, it still continues, after all crossings are finished, to propagate away from that area unchanged.

> what if we put a polarizer at spot C

You can analyze the result separately for each beam, then combine them. This works due to the [principle of superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle): a sum of two EM waves is still a valid solution of the EM wave equation. In other words, the fact that the field is zero at the point doesn't make the behavior special.

Note that, since the waves (by construction) do have full cancellation to zero due to interference, they must have the same polarization.

Answer (score 1):

In the region C you have two plane waves travelling in opposite directions. No matter what the phase relationship, in this configuration you never get cancellation throughout the region. Instead you get a standing wave.

Answer (score 0):

When light from source 1 hits mirror 1, some of it goes to the right and some of it goes down. None of it goes left, so it can not interfere (constructively or destructively) with the beam from source 2. There will be no interference either way at "spot A"

Similarly, when light from source 2 hits mirror 2, some of it goes left and some of it goes down. So there also can't be any interference (constructive or destructive) at "spot B".

Comment: I asked about the interference at C and will after that interference at C the ray from source 1 pass through B as well as will the ray from source 2 pass or be detected at A or will the interference at C cause that A and B will not be reached by the mentioned rays...

Answer (score 0):

EM Wave propagation involves vectors while interferences involve magnitude (square) of vectors. You can have both propagation and interferences. Even standing waves are not what you are thinking: a wave not propagating. It is the superposition of two propagating waves traveling in opposite direction whose superposition can be interpreted as an amplitude time varying non propagating perturbation, but is just an interpretation. In average, the energy getting in equals the energy getting out does not mean the energy does not flow through.